# Change default github branch with Octokit.net

Tags: github-api, octokit.net

I have a small project for updating various settings in GitHub repos. Although I find the repo, the Edit method throws NotFoundException. Any suggestions what could be wrong?
I'm changing from "master" to "develop", both exists.

```
public async Task<Repository> SetDefaultBranch(string repository, string branch)
{
   //var repo = await _client.Repository.Get(_owner, update.Name);
   // the repo is found, but afterwards I receive NotFoundException on Edit

   var update = new RepositoryUpdate(repository) { DefaultBranch = branch };
   return await _client.Repository.Edit(_owner, repository, update);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if you have permissions (as usual). If there is no "Settings" in the navigation breadcrumb, you don't have permission.

Why Octokit.net returns [`NotFoundException`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/Octokit/Exceptions/NotFoundException.cs), rather than [`AuthorizationException`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/Octokit/Exceptions/AuthorizationException.cs) is another story.